# Only 1 of 2 progress bars gets updated in BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a simple form with 2 progressbars and 1 backgroundworker on it.  I have 2 loops (one within the other) and I'd like to report back the progress of each loop once incremented.  Here's the code I have:

```
private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    workerCustomers.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void workerCustomers_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    progressBar2.Value = (int)e.UserState;
}

private void workerCustomers_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    for (int customer = 0; customer < 50; customer++)
    {
        int customerPercentage = ++customer * 100 / 50;
        workerCustomers.ReportProgress(customerPercentage, 0);

        for (int location = 0; location < 500; location++)
        {
            int locationPercentage = ++location * 100 / 500;
            workerCustomers.ReportProgress(customerPercentage, locationPercentage);
        }

        workerCustomers.ReportProgress(customerPercentage, 0);
    }
}
```

When the program runs, progressbar1 gets updated just fine, but progressbar2 never moves.  If I run it through the debugger, I can see the value of progressbar2 being changed, there's just no change graphically.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is the maximum value of the progress bar set properly?

Comment: @lc., yes, by default, it's set to 100 but I've changed that to match the 2nd loop counter total of 500.

Comment: A loop of 500 will go very fast.  It might just not appear to be updating.  Try adding a Thread.Sleep() to the inner loop and see if it is actually just happening too quick for you to see.

Comment: Also, if the maximum for the progressbar is 500, the code you are executing will only ever set it to a max of 100 because you are dividing by 500 then multiplying by 100.

Comment: @JohnKoerner, The outer loop is only going to 50, yet I see the progress on that without an issue, so wouldn't the inner loop of 500 be slower than the outer loop?

Comment: Right but the outer loop is doing 50*500 iterations.  Also calling reportprogress in a tight loop with very little work probably be a performance hit because it takes work to go back to the main thread and raise an event.

Comment: Ok, understood, so how can I achieve what I'm looking to do?

Comment: First, fix your progress bar max value to match what the maximum is (100).  Second either add your work to the inner loop, so it takes more time, or you can simulate it to ensure your gui is working by adding a Thread.Sleep(100), which will have a 100ms delay in each inner loop

Comment: Thank you @JohnKoerner, that fixed it!  Can you post it as the answer so I can give you credit plz.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the 2nd progress bar will fail to update if you have Aero enabled on your desktop.  Which provides the animated progress bar, the one that's green by default with the traveling highlight note.

This progress bar style is special, it interpolates intermediate values and always looks smooth, even if you assign course values to the Value property.  In other words, you can assign 10, 20, 30, etcetera but the bar doesn't jump.  It smoothly increases the bar length.

This has side-effects.  To make this animation work, the progress bar must **lag**.  In other words, it is always showing a value that's *behind* the programmed value.  And some time must pass for it to smoothly increase the bar length to the programmed value.

One more detail you need to know: this animation does *not* happen when you *decrease* the Value property, that immediately jumps the bar length.

So the problem is that you are updating the Value property at a very high rate, much faster than the bar can interpolate.  It can never catch up.  Except when you restart at 0, that immediately jumps the bar.  The rate is so high that the animation can never make it to 1.

You can see this by inserting this statement inside the inner loop:

```
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
```

Play with the argument value, you may need to increase it to 16 to see any difference.  The higher you make it, the further the bar makes it by interpolation.

This is of course not a real problem, this happens because your worker isn't doing any real work.  As soon as you start writing the real code this BGW is supposed to do then you'll also decrease the rate at which you call ProgressChanged.

Comment: thank you for this detailed answer, I learned a lot.  What is the best approach then to this issue?

Comment: I was explicit about that, last paragraph.

Comment: Best answer to this problem. It solved my problem. Thanks. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the fact that your inner loop is so tight that the gui updates are posting too frequently for the gui to accurately respond to them.  The solution is to add your real work to the inner loop, so it takes longer or if you want to simulate the GUI, you can just add a `Thread.Sleep(100)` to simulate the work taking some time.

Also ensure that your progress bar maximums are set to 100, as that is the maximum value you are returning for each.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem comes from a too fast inner loop which means you cant actually see the progress since the updates are too fast for the progressbar to handle.

Your line of code:

```
location * 100 / 500
```

will equal to 100 when you finish the inner loop, so having the progressbar max value set to 500 does not relate well to that number. It means your progressbar will never reach max value.